# How can I disable TextInputs inside a loop based on a specific condition in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to disable some input fields of a row based on a condition. Unfortunately  the jQuery codes in the `inputDisable()` function I wrote does not find the  `<td>` in the table.

```js
function inputDisable() {
  var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
  var quarter = (Math.ceil(month / 3));
  $(".form-control").addClass("bg-danger");

  console.log(quarter);

  if (quarter === 1) {
    $("td.form-control .Q1").prop("disabled", true);
    $("td.form-control .Q2").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q3").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q4").prop("disabled", false);
  } else if (quarter === 2) {
    $("td.form-control .Q1").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q2").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q3").prop("disabled", true);
    $("td.form-control .Q4").prop("disabled", true);
  } else if (quarter === 3) {
    $("td.form-control .Q1").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q2").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q3").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q4").prop("disabled", true);
  } else if (quarter === 4) {
    $("td.form-control .Q1").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q2").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q3").prop("disabled", false);
    $("td.form-control .Q4").prop("disabled", false);
  }
}
```

```js
'<table id="" class="table table-sm table-bordered text-center  mb-1">' +
'<thead>' +
  '<tr>' +
    '<th class="table-info" scope="col">TargetQ1-' + currentYear + '</th>' +
    '<th class="table-info" scope="col">TargetQ2-' + currentYear + '</th>' +
    '<th class="table-info" scope="col">TargetQ3-' + currentYear + '</th>' +
    '<th class="table-info" scope="col">TargetQ4-' + currentYear + '</th>' +
  '</tr>' +
    '<td class="table-active"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number Q1"  name="targetInput1" data-coverageTargetSettingInfoid="' + targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ1 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange(this)" /></td>' +
    '<td class="table-active"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number Q2"  name="targetInput2" data-coverageTargetSettingInfoid="' + targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ2 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange(this)" /></td>' +
    '<td class="table-active"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number Q3"  name="targetInput3" data-coverageTargetSettingInfoid="' + targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ3 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange(this)" /></td>' +
    '<td class="table-active"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number Q4"  name="targetInput4" data-coverageTargetSettingInfoid="' + targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ4 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange(this)" /></td>' +
    '</tr>' +
  '</tbody>' +
'</table>';
```

Comment: Firstly, the table you generate is missing a `<tr>` and `<tbody>` tags. Secondly, none of the `td` gave the class `.form-control`; it's on the child `input`, so the selector needs to be `td .form-control`. Note the space there. Voting to close as a typographical error

Comment: so what does it should be? "td .form-control" does not work , nor does "input .form-control .Q1"  :(

Comment: `td .form-control.Q1`, `td .form-control.Q2` etc

Comment: I found the answer, i should have set the initial value of each row 'disabled':

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are over complicating your selectors.

You could rewrite your inputDisable function in the following way:

```
  function inputDisable() {
      var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
      var quarter = (Math.ceil(month / 3));
      $(".form-control").addClass("bg-danger");

     for (var i = 1; i<= quarter; i++){
         $("input.Q" + i).prop("disabled", false);
     }
}
```

Also, add "disabled" property to all the input fields. You can use jQuery to achieve that or you can manually write it down in all 4 input fields.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach that works:

```
var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
var quarter = (Math.ceil(month / 3));

var q1Disabled = '';
var q2Disabled = '';
var q3Disabled = '';
var q4Disabled = '';


if (quarter === 1) {

    q1Disabled = 'disabled';

} else if (quarter === 2) {

    q1Disabled = 'disabled';
    q2Disabled = 'disabled';
}
```

Comment: How is that an answer? Nowhere in your code are you using any variables named `q1Disabled` or `q2Disabled`

Comment: '<td class="table-active"> <input   type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number Q1"  name="targetInput1" data-coverageTargetSettingInfoid="' +
        targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ1 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange(this)" ' + q1Disabled + ' /></td>' +

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this question as the answer has no relevance to what you explained in the question, and is not going to help any future visitors.

Comment: I could not solve the problem with "selectors" (if anyone has any ideas please do help) so I used the above code instead of the codes mentioned in the question.